# run intent with resource Android

Tags: java, android, uri, android-resources

It is necessary to start intent with an image resource.

```
Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, null); 
            intent.setData(path);
            intent.setType("image/png"); 
            startActivity(intent);
```

There is an error: "the gallery is closed"

Where is my problem?

Comment: You problem is that you forgot to add the question.

Comment: Where are you seeing "the gallery is closed"? LogCat?

Comment: There is a dialogue: "appendices gallery (com.cooliris.media) it is unexpectedly stopped. Repeat attempt."